# I am trying to connect mongodb ATLAS

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server is running on port: ${port}
D:\Practice\mern\mern-exercise\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:290
throw new error_1.MongoParseError(`${optionWord} ${Array.from(unsupportedOptions).join(', ')}  ${isOrAre} not supported`);
^

MongoParseError: option usecreateindex is not supported
at parseOptions (D:\Practice\mern\mern-exercise\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\connection_string.js:290:15)
at new MongoClient (D:\Practice\mern\mern-exercise\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:64:63)
at D:\Practice\mern\mern-exercise\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:801:16
at new Promise ()
at Connection.openUri (D:\Practice\mern\mern-exercise\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:798:19)
at D:\Practice\mern\mern-exercise\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:380:10
at D:\Practice\mern\mern-exercise\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
at new Promise ()
at promiseOrCallback (D:\Practice\mern\mern-exercise\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (D:\Practice\mern\mern-exercise\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1225:10) {
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

Node.js v18.7.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

And the code is

````
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express ();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true}
  );
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', ()=>{
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port: ${port}')
}); 

process.on('warning', e => console.warn(e.stack));```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options)

`useCreateIndex` isn't an option to `mongooose.connect()`